# How to create an small array from large array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using jquery.bracket lib. I want to seperate an large array in pairs like 
`["'Team 1', 'Team 2'"],["'Team 3', 'Team 4'"]` from

```
var all= ["'Team 1', 'Team 2'","'Team 3', 'Team 4'"]
```

I have tried this method:

```
var longArray = all;   
var shortArrays = [], i, len;
for (i = 0, len = longArray.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    shortArrays.push(longArray.slice(i, i +1));
}
```

Following is the code example. I want to call array in this function:

```
var saveData = {
    teams: shortArrays,
}
```

I want `["Team 1","Team 2"],["Team 3","Team 4"]` in `shortArray`.
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `["'Team 1', 'Team 2'"],["'Team 3', 'Team 4'"]` is not the same as `["Team 1","Team 2"],["Team 3","Team 4"]` - What should the output be exactly?

Comment: while Debugging it shows ["'Team 1'",""'Team 2'"] and i have to Pass ['Team1','Team 2']

Comment: var bigData = {
    teams : [ 
      ["'Team 1', 'Team 2'"],["'Team 3', 'Team 4'"], 
    ],   
  }
This what the exact Format i need in shortArray

Comment: `["'Team 1'",""'Team 2'"]` this is a syntax error. You really have to be more careful when posting information...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.splice` which modifies by adding or removing the elements in array.

```
while(longArray.length) // make sure that array has something
      shortArrays.push(longArray.splice(0, 2)); // push the removed items
```

The **Type Signature** of [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

and it removes the first two elements in this case from the array, and *returns* it, which we push in the `shortArrays`.

Comment: Add one more bracket after splice(0, 2).

Comment: @RohilPatel there was a typo. I had typed in `shortArray` instead of `shortArrays`